# Constraining a polymorphic type

Tags: types, functional-programming, ocaml

I've got a range type defined as:

```
type 'a range = Full | Range of ('a * 'a)
```

However, I'd like to constrain 'a to be integer or  float or char, with no other valid types for 'a.

```
Range(0,10) (* valid *)
Range(0.0, 10.0) (* valid *)
Range('a', 'z') (* valid *)
Range("string1", "string2") (* other types like this shouldn't type check *)
```

I figured that I could change my type definitions to:

```
type sequential   = S_int of int | S_float of float | S_char of char ;;
type range = Full | Range of (sequential * sequential);;
```

However, this would then allow something like:

```
Range(S_int(0), S_float(10.0));; (* problem: mixes int and float *)
```

...but I want both components of Range to be the same type.

I suppose that another approach would be to create an int_range type, a float_range type, and a char_range type but I'm wondering if there's another way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Taking a hint from what Haskell would do (declare a type class `(Sequential a) => Range a`) you could use a functor:

```
module Range (S : sig type t end) = struct
  type range = Full | Range of (S.t * S.t)
end
```

and use it to provide the required modules:

```
module IntRange   = Range (struct type t = int   end)
module FloatRange = Range (struct type t = float end)
module CharRange  = Range (struct type t = char  end)
```

The downside is that you lose parametricity on `range`; the upside is that your parametric functions on `range`s now live inside the module `Range`, as they probably should.

In general, `Range`s will make a number of demands of `Sequential`s in order to compensate for the loss of parametricity. These requirements can be cleanly specified in the signature of the functor parameter:

```
module type SEQUENTIAL = sig
  type t
  val to_string : t -> string
  val compare : t -> t -> int
  (* ... *)
end

module Range (S : SEQUENTIAL) = struct
  type t = Full | Range of (S.t * S.t)
  let to_string = function
  | Full -> "full"
  | Range (lo, hi) -> "(" ^ S.to_string lo ^ "," ^ S.to_string hi ^ ")"
  let make lo hi =
    if S.compare lo hi > 0 then Range (hi, lo) else Range (lo, hi)
end
```

To instantiate the `Range` at a specific type you now need to provide a structure that properly parameterizes it:

```
module IntRange = Range (struct
  type t = int
  let to_string = string_of_int
  let compare = Pervasives.compare
end)
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
# IntRange.(to_string (make 4 2)) ;;
- : string = "(2,4)"
```

(using the new syntax for delimited overloading). If you need to hide the implementation of `Range`s behind a signature, you might need to re-export the type of `SEQUENTIAL`s, much as the data structures in the standard library do:

```
module Range (S : SEQUENTIAL) : sig
  type elt = S.t
  type t = private Full | Range of (elt * elt)
  val to_string : t -> string
  val make : elt -> elt -> t
end = struct
  type elt = S.t
  type t = Full | Range of (elt * elt)
  let to_string = function
  | Full -> "full"
  | Range (lo, hi) -> "(" ^ S.to_string lo ^ "," ^ S.to_string hi ^ ")"
  let make lo hi =
    if S.compare lo hi > 0 then Range (hi, lo) else Range (lo, hi)
end
```

This gives you encapsulation and translucent types that can be pattern-matched but not constructed. An alternative to declaring `private` types in the signature is to use a view type or a destructuring function.

Comment: Nice, but taking this to the next level: let's say I want to convert Ranges to strings: How would I define a to_string function in the Range module that would do (S.t -> string) ?

Comment: You need for `SEQUENTIAL` (as a module signature) to provide `Range` with a `to_string`. In effect, every specific requirement on `S.t`s that `Range`s have must be explicitly provided for in the functor parameter.

Comment: to use it: module IntRange = Range (struct type t = int 
                                let to_string v = string_of_int v 
                         end) ;; let r = IntRange.Range(1,10) ;; IntRange.to_string r ;;

Comment: @aneccodeal: yes, I've expanded a bit the example to show how to instantiate the module, how to use the resulting module and possible avenues of extension.

Comment: @Matías, thanks, very nicely documented.  One question: Is this new syntax for delimited overloading in 3.12?  Or is it a camlp4 syntax extension?  When I google the term, it seems to be the latter, not built in.  Is this a proposed 3.13 feature?

Comment: @aneccodeal, the syntax was originally proposed as an CamlP4 extension (pa_do) and incorporated to the base parser in 3.12. You can use it safely with the latest OCaml release.

Answer (score 12):

Another approach is to declare type private and expose functions constructing it only with the types you want, e.g. :

```
module Z : sig
  type 'a range = private Full | Range of ('a * 'a)
  val int_range : int -> int -> int range
  val float_range : float -> float -> float range
  val string_range : string -> string -> string range
  val full : 'a range
end = struct
  type 'a range = Full | Range of ('a * 'a)
  let create x y = Range (x,y)
  let int_range = create
  let float_range = create
  let string_range = create
  let full = Full
end

# open Z;;
# int_range 2 3;;
- : int Z.range = Range (2, 3)
# Range ('a','c');;
Error: Cannot create values of the private type char Z.range
```

Answer (score 0):

OMG modules are so complicated!

```
type 'a range' = [`Full | `Range of 'a * 'a]
type range = [
  | `Int_range of int range'
  | `Float_range of float range'
]
```

Oh dang, we need to add another one:

```
type xrange = [
  | range
  | `String_range of string range'
]
```

Comment: But this allows: `Int_range('a','z');;  : [> `Int_range of char * char ] = `Int_range ('a', 'z') (for example).